# SOLine apply business logic (AKA update price) after updating the orderQty

Tags: acumatica

I've created some code that uses a number of fields (eg: length, width, LbsPerInch) to calculate the order quantity. I've used this:

```
cache.SetValue<SOLine.orderQty>(e.Row, dQO);
```

That part work perfectly. After that's updated, I need to have the line update the rest of the line as though the orderQty was updated manually.

I tried using the following, but that must not be correct, as it seems to just completely hand the form when it runs.

```
Base.Transactions.Update(row);
Base.Transactions.View.RequestRefresh();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user modifies a field on screen it raises the FieldUpdated event for that field.
The base graph you are extending can declare handlers for these FieldUpdated events. The issue could be that the OrderQty field events aren't raised and the base graph uses those events to update other fields which values depend on OrderQty.

The `SetValue` method changes field value without raising field events.

The `SetValueExt` method changes field value and  raises field events.

You can try using `SetValueExt` instead of `SetValue`:

```
cache.SetValueExt<SOLine.orderQty>(e.Row, dQO);
```

This is usually sufficient. The most stubborn refresh issues can usually be dealt with by calling the `RaiseRowUpdated` method to raise the row events after the field has been modified.

Comment: Awesome. That does it. Great info to have.